# Why does the Habitat sample solution have a Sitecore rocks connection for each project

Tags: helix, sitecore-rocks

When browsing through the Habitat solution, I noticed that every project in the solution has a csproj.sitecore file (I assume this is for Sitecore Rocks?). So where we have `Sitecore.Feature.Media.csproj` we also have `Sitecore.Feature.Media.csproj.sitecore` this is repeated for every project in the solution as far as I can tell. This seems a bit unnecessary and is annoying when you want to change it to use a different connection as you then get prompted for every single project in the solution. Surely just one connection is enough?

Comment: You can raise an issue here https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues or even try to resolve this and create a pull request with your fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually done by design. If you read http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/visual-studio/index.html. You will see that by having one Sitecore Rocks reference, it would create one huge reference, not allowing for the projects to be opened separately. This goes against the approach that Habitat is promoting of "your architecture should always have higher priority than any tools or technology". If we were to take the Habitat design approach and implement it into a large scale enterprise environment, with 60 modules, Visual Studio solution would become sluggish. Habitat is promoting separation of concerns into groupings of business functions.

To solve your specific need of connecting to the full Sitecore instance in a single instance Sitecore Rocks connection, you can still do that while leaving the other csproj.sitecore files in tact.